# Group by generates a huge query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query that produces a very big SQL.

```
        var visits = _db.Visits.AsNoTracking().GroupBy(x => x.City)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                City = group.Key.Code, 
                CityName = group.Key.Name, 
                Count = group.Count()
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

Because the `Visits` table has lots of columns. But I am interested in just one column in that Visits table, which I am grouping by.

So this hits performance and query is slow.

How can i make it faster?

Comment: do you have any indexes?\

Comment: What is the SQL that it produces? Is `City` a separate table that `Visits` has a foreign key to?

Comment: I suggest you to run SQL Profiler, preview a query, run it with previewing executing plan and find bottleneck.

Comment: @DanielA.White I have index on CityId, and yes City is another table.

Comment: Why you don't group by CityId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select out just the data you need first so the data set you are working with will be smaller. This should reduce the amount of columns and the size of the query.

```
var visits = _db.Visits.AsNoTracking()
             .Select(c=> new   // reduce the initial data set
             { 
                 City= c.City, 
                 Code = c.Code, 
                 Name = c.Name 
             })
             .GroupBy(x => x.City)
             .Select(group => new    // build results
             {
                 City = group.Key.Code, 
                 CityName = group.Key.Name, 
                 Count = group.Count()
             })
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```